# Show fields of mongolab record with angularjs

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I wanna display the fields names of my records dynamically :

Example:

if i have this three records

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "blahblah"
    },
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age" : "55"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "blahblahblah"
    },
    "firstName": "Johnny",
    "lastName": "Doedoe",
    "weight" : "555lb"

}
```

What i want to display in my web page with angularjs is :

firstname : Jon

lastname : Doe

age : 55

---

firstname : Johnny

lastname : Doedoe

weight : 555lb

I know how to get specific values, for example to get the firstname i can do this : $scope.person.firstname (this is of course an example), but how can i get the label "firstname". How can i ask angularjs to get all the labels ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a query to your DB to get these records, depending on your server that query will look different. The below is a node version of the call

```
function getNames() {
    db.collection.find().toArray(function(data, err) { 
        if (err)
            //do something
        else
            res.send(data);
    });
}
```

Now, from Angular, make a `GET` call to your server:

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    $scope.names = data;
});
```

Now you have `$scope.names` set to your Array of data from the serv. Use an `ng-repeat` to display it all:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <span ng-repeat="(key, val) in name">{{key}}:{{val}}</span>
</div>
```

And that's it (well, basically, undoubtedly you'll have to tweak this).

Comment: But the problem is i don't wanna have to write first, last, age. I want it to be dynamic. Like
` <div ng-repeat="name in names">
    foreach(values as key=>value)
          key : value <br/>
</div> `
I know this isn't a correct code but it's just to help you understand what i want to do! Thanks

Comment: @user -- Edited to accomodate that.

Comment: That works. But i got i last question for you. If i'm displaying only one person. So in my view if i display {{person.name}} that shows the name. If want to do exactly the same thing, it doesn't work :
<span ng-repeat="(key, val) in person">{{key}}:{{val}}</span>
In my js if i want to show data from person, if i do an alert($scope.person.name); it works! so i want to show all the labels : values, but in a single view. Is it possible ?

Comment: Should work, use `object in objects` for an Array of JSON, and `(key, value)` for standard JSON key/val pairs. All i got.

Comment: Yes it works indeed, i did a little mistake when coding. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using Express and Jade with Angular, but alternatively if you don't want to make a separate http request (depends on how your app is configured) you could write an angular service that can be reused with any controller.

The purpose of the service would be to grab json and put it into your current scope so your controller can use it. Also you can inject this service dependency on every page (i.e. in every controller) and it'll load your documents for you.

Blog post and [full repo here](http://chrisckchang.com/2013/10/17/passing-json-from-express-to-angular-and-jade/).